# How to restrict values in Winforms MaskedTextbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

My requirement is that the user will enter a time ("HH:mm:ss") in masked text box and based on that time i am doing some functionalities. My problem is i can mask the time but i can't restrict the user to enter up to 23 for hours,59 for minutes and 59 for seconds.
How to fix this.

**C# Code**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    maskTxtAlert1.Mask = "00:00:00";
        maskTxtAlert1.CutCopyMaskFormat = MaskFormat.ExcludePromptAndLiterals;
 }

 private void maskTxtAlert1_MaskInputRejected(object sender, MaskInputRejectedEventArgs e)
 {
            if (e.Position == maskTxtAlert1.Mask.Length)
           {
               string errorMessage = "You cannot add extra characters";
               toolTip1.ToolTipTitle = "Input Rejected - No more inputs allowed";
               toolTip1.Show(errorMessage, maskTxtAlert1, 12, 24, 2000);
               errorProvider1.BlinkStyle = ErrorBlinkStyle.AlwaysBlink;
               errorProvider1.SetError(maskTxtAlert1, errorMessage);
           }
           else
           {
               toolTip1.ToolTipTitle = "Input Rejected";
               string errorMessage = "You can only add numeric characters (0-9).";
               toolTip1.Show(errorMessage, maskTxtAlert1, 12, 24, 2000);
               errorProvider1.BlinkStyle = ErrorBlinkStyle.AlwaysBlink;
               errorProvider1.SetError(maskTxtAlert1, errorMessage);
           }
   }

 private void maskTxtAlert1_TypeValidationCompleted(object sender, TypeValidationEventArgs e)
 {
           MessageBox.Show("Enter Valid as One");
 }
```

Comment: Why you dont use javascript for this issue http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/  $("#time").mask("99:99:99");

Comment: Because he is talking about a WinForms application

Comment: Why don't you use a DateTimePicker with .Format = Time and .ShowUpDown = True?

Comment: Did you try by setting `ValidatingType` to `DateTime`

Comment: @V4Vendetta how to set the property ValidatingType to datetime

Comment: @Vignesh `maskedTextBox.ValidatingType = typeof(DateTime);` however it doesn't work. BTW, I think you should try a normal `TextBox` with some playing with `Regular Expression`. `MaskedTextBox` is not used for your purpose.

Answer (score 4):

I think its better to use DateTimePicker as tezzo said and no validation required

```
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
//For 24 H format
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "HH:mm:ss";
//For 12 H format
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "hh:mm:ss tt";
dateTimePicker1.ShowUpDown = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a [`DateTimePickerFormat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker) with [`.CustomFormat = "HH:mm:ss"`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat) is probably the best out of the box approach, but can be restrictive in terms of UI interaction.

For people coming here looking for adding validation to a [`MaskedTextBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox), there are several good options.

#### Type Validation

If you still want automatic parsing, you can can add a [`ValidatingType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.validatingtype) and tap into the [`TypeValidationCompleted`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.typevalidationcompleted) Event like this:

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        MaskedTextBox1.Mask = "00:00"
        MaskedTextBox1.ValidatingType = GetType(DateTime)
End Sub

Private Sub MaskedTextBox1_TypeValidationCompleted(sender As Object, e As TypeValidationEventArgs) _
    Handles MaskedTextBox1.TypeValidationCompleted
    If Not e.IsValidInput Then
        Me.validationToolTip.ToolTipTitle = "Invalid Time"
        Me.validationToolTip.Show("The time you supplied must be a valid time in the format HH:mm", sender)
    End If
End Sub
```

`ValidatingType` will tap into the `public static Object Parse(string)` method for each type it's passed.  You can even pass in your own custom classes as long as they implement this signature

#### Custom Validation:

To provide your own custom validation, you can tap into the [`Validating`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating) Event like this:

```vb
Private Sub MaskedTextBox1_Validating(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) _
    Handles MaskedTextBox1.Validating
    Dim senderAsMask = DirectCast(sender, MaskedTextBox)
    Dim value = senderAsMask.Text
    Dim parsable = Date.TryParse(value, New Date)

    If Not parsable Then
        e.Cancel = True
        Me.validationToolTip.ToolTipTitle = "Invalid Time"
        Me.validationToolTip.Show("The time you supplied must be a valid time in the format HH:mm", sender)
    End If
End Sub
```

In this case, the validation implementation is still rather naive, but you could implement whatever logic you want to determine validity.

> **Notes**:
> If the `CausesValidation` property is set to **false**, the `Validating` and `Validated` events are suppressed.
> If the `Cancel` property of the `CancelEventArgs` is set to **true** in the Validating event delegate, all events that would usually occur after the `Validating` event are suppressed.

For Bonus Points, hide the tooltip when the user starts typing again:

```vb
Private Sub MaskedTextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs) _
    Handles MaskedTextBox1.KeyDown
    Me.validationToolTip.Hide(sender)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have to use `maskedTextBox` as tezzo said, but that might be less convenient. i would chose a simpler way: instead of poping a `messageBox` on `TypeValidationCompleted` you can change invalid user values. if the user wrote a value higher then 23 in hours for example, change it to 23

Answer (score 0):

The MaskedTextbox class is not built to handle this type of validation and you will have to do add some manual validation to the Validation Complete event.

e.g.

```
string[] timedetails = FormattedDate.Split(':');
int hours = Int32.Parse(timedetails[0].Trim());
int minutes = Int32.Parse(timedetails[1].Trim());
int seconds = Int32.Parse(timedetails[2].Trim());

if(hours > 23)
{
   //error message here, etc.
}
```

However, you may be much better off using a formatted DateTime control probably set to long time format. See [full listing of formats on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx).